# SharePoint 2016 wrong parent content type

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

i have a big problem with sharepoint and my content types which i create with the element.xml schema.

I have two content types.

- Content Type 1: 0x0100680417ddb3154267b4a1dca0832770e8
- Content Type 2: 0x0100f42fc440e1b3464a988bfd7358bcf726

The parent of these types are item.
When i deploy this content types this is correct.

But my lists which references to these content types have a child of my content types of type item.
In sharepoint this looks like this:

- Item (Root) - ID: 0x01
- MyContentType (child of root) - ID: 0x0100680417ddb3154267b4a1dca0832770e8
- Item (Child of my content type) -  ID:0x0100680417ddb3154267b4a1dca0832770e80036C4E5FA0DF8F14BB180C23C01F22B28

Do you know why sharepoint creates a child content type of mine?

Here is one of my content type definitions which creates an incorrect order:

```
<ContentType ID="0x0100680417ddb3154267b4a1dca0832770e8" Name="Orders" Group="CustomOrders" Description="My Orders" Inherits="TRUE" Hidden="FALSE" Version="0" Sealed="FALSE" Overwrite="TRUE">
<FieldRefs>
  <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Name" DisplayName="Name" />
  <FieldRef ID="{86bbed44-634e-4e7a-914b-c9cd93e40122}" />
</FieldRefs>
```

Do you know what is wrong in my definition or why sharepoint creates childs of my content types?

Comment: This is expected behavior when a content type is added to a list

Comment: Ok thanks, but why are my llokup fields don't work? When i create the lists and fields in sharepoint it works like a charme. The lookup dropdown shows an error: "this service isn't available right now"